# Aws Amplify : non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-amplify

I had SPA React app which is user portal uses Azure AD via Cognito was running in aws amplify. Once I deployed new version of app, the page shows empty blank page and console error is:

Did not parse stylesheet at 'https://develop.kslfckldhfks.amplifyapp.com/generator/login/static/css/main.8aaff038.chunk.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing a similar issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Removed <Link> components, then it worked!